# Style is not recognized when using mpdf

Tags: php, mpdf

**Here is my code:**

```
    $htmls ='<html><body style="font-size:100px;">
    <table style="width:100%;border-spacing: 0px; margin-top: 10px;background-color: #FF5733;font-size:100px;" >
                      <tr>
                         <td  style="padding: 5px 8px; font-weight: bold;">TEST</td>
                         <td style="padding: 5px 8px;"> Test1 </td>
                         <td style="padding: 5px 8px;"> Test2 </td>
                      </tr>
                  </table></body></html>';
    
       require './mpdf60/mpdf.php';
       $mpdf = new mPDF('utf-8', 'A4', 1);
       $mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
       $mpdf->autoLangToFont = true;
       $mpdf->autoScriptToLang = true;
       $mpdf->useSubstitutions = false;
       $mpdf->simpleTables = true;
       $mpdf->packTableData = true;
       $mpdf->showImageErrors = true;
       $mpdf->list_indent_first_level = 0;
       $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
       $fname = date('Y-m-d-h-i-s') . ".pdf";
       $mpdf->Output(__DIR__ . "/pdf/" . $fname);
       $filePath =__DIR__ . "/pdf/" . $fname;
```

**Output:**

[image]

**I need it.**

[image]

How to fix it. Creating a `css` file is difficult for me because I use different styles on all tags.

Comment: Which version of mPDF are you using?

Comment: Nevermind, missed the `require_once()` line that specifies 6.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using an older version of mPDF. Its current stable release is *2 major versions* ahead of the version you're using.

Your code contains a typo. Change `$htmls` to `$html`.

When I test your code with mPDF 8(.0.7), things work swimmingly, and this is the output I get:

[image: Output from my test of your fixed code with mPDF 8]

Comment: Hello. I am a beginner and learned a lot. Thank you so much. It's working.